# Find Tangent Line Common to Two Hippopedes Curves

Tags: tangent-line

Hello and forgive me for my lack of formality or perhaps poor wording. I am trying to derive the equations for tangent lines common to two Hippopedes ovals with different origins (see [Booth's Curve](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/booth/booth.shtml)):

$$(x^2+y^2)^2 = a^2x^2 + b^2y^2
$$

and

$$((x-h)^2+(y-k)^2)^2 = a^2(x-h)^2 + b^2(y-k)^2
$$

Here is an example:

[image: Example]

I believe the solution steps should be something along the lines of:

1. Find derivatives of each curve ($y'_1$ and $y'_2$)
2. Set derivatives equal to each other (Eq. 1)
3. Write slope of line as $y_1-y_0/x_1-x_0$.
4. Set slope equal to either $y'_1$ or $y'_2$. (Eq. 2)

then solve Eq. 1 and 2 simultaneously. I'm anticipating the math will be cumbersome, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Common tangents are parallel to the line connecting $(0,0)$ and $(h,k)$

Comment: @Raffaele Not necessarily. e.g. If h=10, k=0, you would be right for the two horizontal lines joining the top and bottoms of each curve, but would have missed the other two curves. I will add an illustration to clarify what I am looking for.

Comment: It's clear. I gave as granted that the curves intersected. Anyway the two other tangents when they don't intersect meet in the midpoint of the two centers

Comment: @Raffaele Would you be able to provide me an example as an answer?

Comment: Alternatively, I'm wondering if I plug "mx+c" for y in the above and solve that way?

Comment: https://imgur.com/3TS9sEr

Comment: @Raffaele Did you use Geogebra to solve that? How did you solve that? Also, what proof do you have that the tangent line bisects the line containing the centers?

Comment: No, I solved nothing. In GeoGebra you can use parametric lines which change as you move a cursor

Comment: Wait! Is this considered a common tangent? https://imgur.com/lDbdvr0

Comment: @Raffaele No, in regards to your second image, you are okay. I want tangents which intersect each curve at exactly one point. In the second image, the line intersects one of the curves more than once, so it does not count.

Comment: @Raffaele Thank you for your help as well! I wish I could give you points for credit too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These ovals have parameterisations

$(x(t),y(t))=(b\frac{ab\cos(t)}{b^2(\cos(t))^2+a^2(\sin(t))^2},a\frac{ab\sin(t)}{b^2(\cos(t))^2+a^2(\sin(t))^2})$ and $(x(t),y(t))=(h+b\frac{ab\cos(t)}{b^2(\cos(t))^2+a^2(\sin(t))^2},k+a\frac{ab\sin(t)}{b^2(\cos(t))^2+a^2(\sin(t))^2}).$

The [dual curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve) are given by $(p(t),q(t))=(\frac{-y'(t)}{x'(t)y(t)-x(t)y'(t)},\frac{x'(t)}{x'(t)y(t)-x(t)y'(t)}).$

Now find the intersection points $P_i$ of the dual curves. Then the common tangents are the lines $x x(P_i)+y y(P_i)=1.$

The picture below shows only a few of the common tangents:

[image: hpct3]

Here are the dual curves. Note that they have nodes corresponding to the bitangents.

[image: hpduals]

To accentuate the node bitangent correspondence, here are both the curve and its dual, the point and the dual line (bitangent).

[image: hpbitangent]

The red intersection point $P_3: (l,m)$ corresponds to the red common tangent through the correspondence $(l:m:-1)$ to $lx +my-1=0.$

[image: hpintersection]

I used $a=0.5, b=2.3, h=2.95, k=0.85$ with the following to get the plot

```
curve(((a^2*b*sin(t)*(2*a^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2*b^2*cos(t)*sin(t)))  /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)^2  -(a^2*b*cos(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2))  /((a^2*b*sin(t)        *((-(a*b^2*sin(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2))         -(a*b^2*cos(t)*(2*a^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2*b^2*cos(t)*sin(t)))          /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)^2))   /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)   -(a*b^2*cos(t)      *((a^2*b*cos(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)       -(a^2*b*sin(t)*(2*a^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2*b^2*cos(t)*sin(t)))        /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)^2))    /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)),((-(a*b^2*sin(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2))  -(a*b^2*cos(t)*(2*a^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2*b^2*cos(t)*sin(t)))   /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)^2)  /((a^2*b*sin(t)        *((-(a*b^2*sin(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2))         -(a*b^2*cos(t)*(2*a^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2*b^2*cos(t)*sin(t)))          /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)^2))   /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)   -(a*b^2*cos(t)      *((a^2*b*cos(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)       -(a^2*b*sin(t)*(2*a^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2*b^2*cos(t)*sin(t)))        /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)^2))    /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)),t,0,2pi)
curve(((a^2*b*sin(t)*(2*a^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2*b^2*cos(t)*sin(t)))  /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)^2  -(a^2*b*cos(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2))  /(((a^2*b*sin(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)+k)   *((-(a*b^2*sin(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2))    -(a*b^2*cos(t)*(2*a^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2*b^2*cos(t)*sin(t)))     /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)^2)   -((a^2*b*cos(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)    -(a^2*b*sin(t)*(2*a^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2*b^2*cos(t)*sin(t)))     /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)^2)    *((a*b^2*cos(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)+h)), ((-(a*b^2*sin(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2))  -(a*b^2*cos(t)*(2*a^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2*b^2*cos(t)*sin(t)))   /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)^2)  /(((a^2*b*sin(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)+k)   *((-(a*b^2*sin(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2))    -(a*b^2*cos(t)*(2*a^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2*b^2*cos(t)*sin(t)))     /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)^2)   -((a^2*b*cos(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)    -(a^2*b*sin(t)*(2*a^2*cos(t)*sin(t)-2*b^2*cos(t)*sin(t)))     /(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)^2)    *((a*b^2*cos(t))/(a^2*sin(t)^2+b^2*cos(t)^2)+h)),t,0,2pi)
```

There are ways to get the implicit equations defining the dual curves (I'd need to read up on them), and you could further use grobner bases.

The first has equation $a^4b^{10}x^6+3a^6b^8x^4y^2+3a^8b^6x^2y^4+a^{10}b^4y^6+(8a^6b^6-8a^4b^8-a^2b^{10})x^4+(-20a^8b^4+38a^6b^6-20a^4b^8)x^2y^2+(-a^{10}b^2-8a^8b^4+8a^6b^6)y^4+(16a^8b^2-32a^6b^4+8a^4b^6+8a^2b^8)x^2+(8a^8b^2+8a^6b^4-32a^4b^6+16a^2b^8)y^2-16a^6b^2+32a^4b^4-16a^2b^6=0$

Comment: Okland Can you go into a little more detail about how to calculate the intersection points themselves?

Comment: @A.Hendry I used the intersect command in geogebra.

Comment: @Jan-Magnus_Okland I'm not sure I understand the dual curves image you posted.

Comment: Without using geogebra, how would you calculate the intersection points? (I'm trying to derive general equations)

Comment: Would Mathematica or a similar solver be necessary to get general equations for these intersection points?

Comment: In the above, when you use $xx(P_i) + yy(P_i) = 1$, are these in line coordinates? (i.e. $lx + my + 1 = 0$)?

Comment: More like $l x+m y-1=0,$ where $l=x(P_i),m=y(P_i).$

Comment: I see. Thank you. These are several new concepts for me and I appreciate your help. So there are two dual curves (black is for the Hippopedes oval at origin, blue for the  translated $(h,k)$ one). The intersection points between the black and blue curves yield the $P_i$ for the common tangent lines. Is that correct? Can you also show me on your graphs the nodes you speak of that correspond to the bitangents?

Comment: @A.Hendry See the edit.

Comment: Instead, can you show me the nodes for the bitangents across each curve, not across an individual curve? Those are the ones I'm interested in, sorry. Is there a way to know which nodes lead to the types of bitangents that occur?

Comment: That’s what bitangents are. Common tangents correspond in the same way though.

Comment: Oh, forgive me. I didn't know the difference between bitangent and common tangent. I meant common tangent. I apologize. Can you show me a node for a common tangent?

Comment: And $P_i$ is a parameter like $t$, not an $(x, y)$ point, right?

Comment: $P_i$ is a point.

Comment: I see now! Thank you so much!

Comment: $P_3: (0.71,-0.13)$ corresponding to $0.71 x-0.13 y-1=0.$

Comment: Yes, you're right. I deleted the comment I previously made regarding the bitangent node as I was wrong (it is $~(-0.42,0)$, not $~(0,-0.42)$). And thank you for all your help! I totally get it now!

Comment: For posterity: As @Jan-MagnusOkland beautifully states, $P_i = (l_i, m_i)$ and $l_i$ and $m_i$ are the negative reciprocals of the $x$ and $y$ intercepts for the tangent line (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_coordinates). So, if you know roughly where these intercepts will be for your desired line, you can search the space of intersection points correspondingly to find your line! Brilliant!