# Find Cross-Tangents to Offset Ellipses

Tags: conic-sections, projective-geometry

**Question:**

I am stuying projective geometry and would like to find an analytic solution to my problem. This is a follow-up to [my older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3884907/find-tangent-line-common-to-two-hippopedes-curves).

Given two ellipses with the same major and minor axes, but different origins (written in homogeneous coordinates):

$$
\frac{x_1^2}{a^2} + \frac{y_1^2}{b^2} - 1 = 0
$$

and

$$
\frac{(x_2-h)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y_2-k)^2}{b^2} - 1 = 0
$$

what are the equations of the cross-tangents to the two ellipses? Assume $h, k, a,$ and $b$ are all knowns.

**My Attempt:**

Following the method from [my older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3884907/find-tangent-line-common-to-two-hippopedes-curves), it makes sense to find the intersection points of the dual curves to each ellipse. Let $f_1$ be the implicit homogeneous function defining our first ellipse (i.e. $f_1(x_1, y_1, z_1) = 0$) and $f_2$ that of our second, respectively. The dual curve of an ellipse is an ellipse (at least, AFAIK, for an ellipse at the origin), which [Wikipedia shows nicely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve).

Hence, our first dual is

$$
a^2 X_1^2 + b^2 Y_1^2 = 1.
$$

I am having trouble finding the second dual (namely, that of the ellipse centered at $(h,k)$). Could someone please help me in deriving this? Is this the simplest way to solve this problem?

Following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve), about the closest I get to is the following and I don't know how to eliminate $\lambda$:

$$
\frac{a^2}{2\lambda} \left( X_2 + \frac{\lambda h}{a^2} \right)^2 + \frac{b^2}{2\lambda} \left( Y_2 + \frac{\lambda k}{b^2} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{\lambda}{2} \right) \left( \left( \frac{h}{a} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{k}{b} \right)^2 \right)
 + 1 = 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dual conics are for $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$ given by $$ (-\frac14e^2+cf)x^2+(\frac12de-bf)xy+(-\frac14d^2+af)y^2+(-cd+\frac12be)x+(\frac12bd-ae)y-\frac14b^2+ac=0$$ or $\begin{pmatrix}x&y&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&\frac{b}{2}&\frac{d}{2}\\\frac{b}{2}&c&\frac{e}{2}\\\frac{d}{2}&\frac{e}{2}&f\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{pmatrix}$ to $$\begin{pmatrix}x&y&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-\frac14e^2+cf&\frac{\frac12de-bf}{2}&\frac{-cd+\frac12be}{2}\\\frac{\frac12de-bf}{2}&-\frac14d^2+af&\frac{\frac12bd-ae}{2}\\\frac{-cd+\frac12be}{2}&\frac{\frac12bd-ae}{2}&-\frac14b^2+ac\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

from which you can see it's to do with the matrix of a conic and it's adjoint matrix which is the inverse when divided by the determinant. In your special case:

```
k^2*y^2-b^2*y^2+2*h*k*x*y+2*k*y+h^2*x^2-a^2*x^2+2*h*x+1=0
(-b^2*y^2)-a^2*x^2+1=0
```

Now solve for intersection points

```
solve([((b^2*h^2+a^2*k^2)*y^2-h^2)*((b^2*h^2+a^2*k^2)*y^2+4*a^2*k*y+4*a^2-h^2),(2*a^2*b^2*h^3+2*a^4*h*k^2-2*a^2*h^3*k^2)*x+(b^4*h^4*k+2*a^2*b^2*h^2*k^3+a^4*k^5)*y^3+(-b^4*h^4+2*a^2*b^2*h^2*k^2+3*a^4*k^4)*y^2+(2*a^2*b^2*h^2*k-b^2*h^4*k+2*a^4*k^3-3*a^2*h^2*k^3)*y+b^2*h^4-3*a^2*h^2*k^2],[x,y]);

[[x = k/sqrt(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2),y = -h/sqrt(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2)],
     [x = -k/sqrt(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2),y = h/sqrt(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2)],
     [x = (k*sqrt(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2-4*a^2*b^2)-2*b^2*h)/(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2),
      y = -(h*sqrt(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2-4*a^2*b^2)+2*a^2*k)/(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2)],
     [x = -(k*sqrt(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2-4*a^2*b^2)+2*b^2*h)/(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2),
      y = (h*sqrt(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2-4*a^2*b^2)-2*a^2*k)/(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2)]]
```

So the cross tangents are $$x  \frac{k\sqrt{a^2k^2+b^2h^2-4a^2b^2}-2b^2h}{a^2k^2+b^2h^2}+y \frac{ -(h\sqrt{a^2k^2+b^2h^2-4a^2b^2}+2a^2k)}{a^2k^2+b^2h^2}+1=0\\
 x \frac{-(k\sqrt{a^2k^2+b^2h^2-4a^2b^2}+2b^2h)}{a^2k^2+b^2h^2}+
  y \frac{h\sqrt{a^2k^2+b^2h^2-4a^2b^2}-2a^2k}{a^2k^2+b^2h^2}+1=0.$$

Comment: what's a good book to learn this from? I've studied Coxeter's "Projective Geometry", but it doesn't go into calculating dual curves.

Comment: @A.Hendry I learned it from the introduction to Gelfand Kapranov Zelevinsky Discriminants, Resultants, and Multidimensional Determinants.

Comment: I know this is another question, but can you show me why for a parametric curve, the dual is given by $X=\frac{y'}{yx'-xy'}$, $Y=\frac{x'}{xy'-yx'}$? I don't follow how that was derived.

Comment: To be fair, I'll ask this as a separate question :)

Comment: Okland, How did you derive the equations for the dual conics? I want to know how to do this for implicit functions rather than parametric ones.

Comment: okland Did you homogenize some terms to get the first dual conic? How did you arrive at the dual conic for the ellipse at $(h,k)$?

Comment: @A.Hendry: See the edit.

Comment: What software did you use to solve for the intersection points and how did you formulate the terms as you've shown?

Comment: @A.Hendry: I used maxima CAS on the grobner basis of the system as Macaulay2 found it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Rescale using $au:=x,bv:=y$ and you get two circles,

$$u^2+v^2=1,\\(u-u_c)^2+(v-v_c)^2=1.$$

Rotating around the origin, you can reduce the second to

$$(u-d)^2+v^2=1.$$

The cross-tangents pass through $(\dfrac d2,0)$ and by $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, with

$$\cos\theta\,(\cos\theta-\frac d2)+\sin^2\theta=0.$$

Write the equations of these lines and reverse the transformations.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm still struggling...Can you please help me a little further? This is still new to me. I added edits to your answer with my continued work because I don't think they would fit here. Let me know if you cannot see them.

Comment: @A.Hendry: where are you stuck ? There are 9 lines in my post.

Comment: I don't know how to write the equations for the lines and I'm not sure what the last equation you wrote with theta means? Is that a form of xX + yY = 1, as I asked in my edits?

Comment: Would you be willing to show the complete answer with the actual equations?

Comment: @A.Hendry: lookup "line by two points". Solve the last equation for $\theta$.

Comment: Great hint, but I am going to accept the other answer only because it provides a complete solution and it is in terms of projective geometry. Thank you again for this hint!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to expand on the answer I accepted for my own sake and the sake of those reading this in the future. My post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4058497/derivation-of-dual-curve-for-parametric-equations?noredirect=1#comment8384509_4058497) is also instructive for this problem.

If the equation of a line in [line coordintes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_coordinates) is

$$
Xx+Yy+1=0 \tag{1}
$$

and the tangent to our curve at point $(x_0)$ (identically $(p,q,r)$ on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve)) $<f_x \left. \right|_p, f_y \left. \right|_q, 0>$, denoted $(x')$, is coincident with the line if its inner product with the line coordinates is $0$ per [Coxeter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387406239)

$$
Xx'+Yy'=0
$$

where $(x')=(x',y',0)$, then

$$
Xf_x \left. \right|_p + Yf_y \left. \right|_q = 0. \tag{2}
$$

Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ simultaneously yields

$$
X = \frac{-f_y \left. \right|_q}{xf_y \left. \right|_q-yf_x \left. \right|_p}  
$$
$$
Y = \frac{f_x \left. \right|_q}{xf_y \left. \right|_q-yf_x \left. \right|_p}
$$