# Derivation of Dual Curve for Parametric Equations

Tags: parametric, projective-geometry, dual-maps

I am studying projective geometry and am stuck on understanding the following:

For a parametric curve

$$
x = x(t), y = y(t)
$$

the *dual curve* is given by

$$
X=\frac{-y′}{xy′-yx'},
Y=\frac{x′}{xy′−yx′}
$$

This is explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve), in Chapter 1, Section 2 of *Discriminants, Resultants, and Multidimensional Determinants* by Gelfand, Kapranov, and Zelevinsky (referred by @Jan-Magnus-Økland; see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4054110/find-cross-tangents-to-offset-ellipses/4054720#4054720)), and [in this document](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emonks/papers/DualityV3.pdf).

I feel like something so simple and fundamental is escaping me...how was this derived? Is Cramer's Rule involved?

Comment: There's a subtlety here: take $x^2+y^2-1=0$ and a parametrization, say,  $x=\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1},y=\frac{2t}{t^2+1}.$ Then using the above formulas you get $X=-\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1},Y=-\frac{2t}{t^2+1}$ and line corresponding becomes $xX+yY-1=0,$ while via the matrix formulation the circle is self-dual and for $X^2+Y^2-1=0$ a corresponding line is $xX+yY+1=0.$

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Are the two lines $xX+yY-1=0$ and $xX+yY+1=0$ equivalent because we could multiply one or the other by $-1$ or $1$ since the coordinates are homogeneous?

Comment: It's true the line comes from xX+yY+zZ=0 homogeneous, maybe z=1 and Z=-1? Still it's baffling that the two methods don't agree.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion which stems from [wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3ADual.webm), For the circle (and ellipses centered at the origin) both $xX+yY-1=0$ and $xX+yY+1=0$ are tangents, but for general conics $xX+yY+1=0$ is the correct tangent.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Not at all. Thank you for looking into it! If the methods weren't consistent/didn't agree, I certainly wouldn't want to use one or the other. Your appreciation for mathematics is readily apparent and very valuable :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$
Xx + Yy + 1 = 0 \tag{1}
$$

be the equation of a line in [line coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_coordinates). A point $(x)$ and line $[X]$  (in the notation of [Coxeter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387406239)) are said to be *incident* in projective geometry if their inner product is zero:

$$
\{xX\} = 0.
$$

The tangent to our parametric equation at point $t_0$ is given by $<x'(t_0),y'(t_0)>$. Hence, the point $(x')$ is incident on our line if

$$
\{x'X\} = 0.
$$

That is,

$$
Xx' + Yy' = 0 \tag{2}
$$

Thus, we have two equations in two unknowns ($(1)$ and $(2)$), which via Cramer's rule yield

$$
X=\frac{-y'}{xy'-yx'},  
Y=\frac{x'}{xy'-yx'}.
$$

Q.E.D.