# Derive Equation for Dual Curve to Ellipse not at Origin Given Implicitly

Tags: projective-geometry, dual-spaces

This is a second follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4054110/find-cross-tangents-to-offset-ellipses/4060630#4060630). For the ellipse centered at $(h,k)$ defined implicitly as

$$
\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}-1=0 \tag{1}
$$

Please show the steps for calculating its dual curve and provide the equation for the dual curve. **Do not solve by redefining the function parametrically.** I know how to solve for parametric functions, but need to see the general algorithm for implicit functions.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_curve#Polar_reciprocal) provides a trivial example that does not help me.

**My Attempt**

At point $(p,q)$,

$$
X = \lambda \frac{2(p-h)}{a^2} \implies p = h + \left( \frac{a^2}{2\lambda} \right) X
$$

$$
Y = \lambda \frac{2(q-k)}{b^2} \implies q = k + \left( \frac{b^2}{2\lambda} \right) Y
$$

For incidence to occur, the inner product of the line $[X,Y]$ and point $(p,q)$ must be zero:

$$
\frac{a^2}{2\lambda}X^2 + hX + \frac{b^2}{2\lambda}Y^2 + kY = 0
$$

$$
a^2X^2 + b^2Y^2 + 2\lambda (hX + kY) = 0 \tag{2}
$$

How should $\lambda$ be eliminated at this point?

**Thought 1:**

Can we homogenize the linear terms by $\frac{\left( hX + kY \right)}{-2\lambda}$? If so, we get

$$
a^2X^2 + b^2Y^2 - (hX+kY)^2 = 0
$$

$$
a^2X^2 + b^2Y^2 - (h^2X^2 + 2hkXY + k^2Y^2) = 0
$$

$$
(a^2-h^2)X^2 + (b^2-k^2)Y^2 - 2hkXY = 0
$$

but I'm not sure if this is the correct equation for the dual. Is there a way to check?

**Thought 2:**

Alternatively, can I just say that $\lambda = 1$? In this case, I get:

$$
a^2X^2+b^2Y^2+2(hX+kY)=0
$$

However, now my answer in Thought 1 is different from Thought 2.

Comment: First multiply through with $a^2b^2$ expand and homogenize the equation:

$$(a^2k^2+b^2h^2-a^2b^2)z^2-2a^2kyz-2b^2hxz+a^2y^2+b^2x^2=0$$

Then the system is

$$\begin{align}X-\lambda (2b^2p-2b^2hr)&=0\\
Y-\lambda (2a^2q-2a^2kr)&=0\\
Z-\lambda (2(a^2k^2+b^2h^2-a^2b^2)r-2a^2kq-2b^2hp)&=0\\
Xp+Yq+Zr&=0\end{align}$$

Comment: So I homogenized the wrong equation in **Thought 1**? I should have homogenized the original conic (1) rather than the dual form (2)?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thank you so much for everything! And I will definitely look into Macaulay2 and Grobner bases!

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland So, just to be clear, the moral of the story is that you must homogenize the _original_ equation before pursuing the lambda method, not the dual equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dual conics are for $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$ given by $$ (-\frac14e^2+cf)x^2+(\frac12de-bf)xy+(-\frac14d^2+af)y^2+(-cd+\frac12be)x+(\frac12bd-ae)y-\frac14b^2+ac=0$$ or $\begin{pmatrix}x&y&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a&\frac{b}{2}&\frac{d}{2}\\\frac{b}{2}&c&\frac{e}{2}\\\frac{d}{2}&\frac{e}{2}&f\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{pmatrix}$ to $$\begin{pmatrix}x&y&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-\frac14e^2+cf&\frac{\frac12de-bf}{2}&\frac{-cd+\frac12be}{2}\\\frac{\frac12de-bf}{2}&-\frac14d^2+af&\frac{\frac12bd-ae}{2}\\\frac{-cd+\frac12be}{2}&\frac{\frac12bd-ae}{2}&-\frac14b^2+ac\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

from which you can see it's to do with the matrix of a conic and it's adjoint matrix which is the inverse when divided by the determinant.

For an explicit derivation see [Perspectives on Projective Geometry by Jürgen Richter-Gebert](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-17286-1):

> A conic consists of all points p that satisfy an equation $p^TAp = 0.$ The set
> of all tangents to this conic can be described as $\{Ap | p^TAp = 0\}.$ We can
> describe this set of homogeneous coordinates for lines directly as a quadratic
> form by the following observation:
>
> $p^TAp = p^TAA^{−1}Ap = p^TA^TA^{−1}Ap = (Ap)^TA^{−1}(Ap).$
>
> The right side of the equation explains how the set of tangent lines of a
> conic may be directly interpreted as the zero set of a quadratic form with
> matrix $A^{−1}$.

**Edit:**

The $\lambda$-method works in [Macaulay2](https://www.unimelb-macaulay2.cloud.edu.au/#home):

```
R=QQ[a,b,c,d,e,f]
S=R[l]
T=S[p,q,r,X,Y,Z,MonomialOrder=>Lex]
I=ideal(X-l*(2*a*p+b*q+d*r),Y-l*(b*p+2*q*c+e*r),Z-l*(d*p+e*q+2*f*r),X*p+Y*q+Z*r)
gens gb I -- matrix {{(e^2-4*c*f)*X^2+(-2*d*e+4*b*f)*X*Y+(4*c*d-2*b*e)*X*Z+(d^2-4*a*f)*Y^2+(-2*b*d+4*a*e)*Y*Z+(b^2-4*a*c)*Z^2, (2*c*d^2-2*b*d*e+2*a*e^2+2*b^2*f-8*a*c*f)*l*r+(-2*c*d+b*e)*X+(b*d-2*a*e)*Y+(-b^2+4*a*c)*Z,(e^2-4*c*f)*l*r*X+(-d*e+2*b*f)*l*r*Y+(2*c*d-b*e)*l*r*Z-e*X*Y+2*c*X*Z+d*Y^2-b*Y*Z, (d*e-2*b*f)*l*r*X+(-d^2+4*a*f)*l*r*Y+(b*d-2*a*e)*l*r*Z-e*X^2+d*X*Y+b*X*Z-2*a*Y*Z,(2*c*d-b*e)*l*r*X+(-b*d+2*a*e)*l*r*Y+(b^2-4*a*c)*l*r*Z-2*c*X^2+2*b*X*Y-2*a*Y^2, (2*c*d-b*e)*l*q+(d*e-2*b*f)*l*r-d*Y+b*Z, (b*d-2*a*e)*l*q+(d^2-4*a*f)*l*r-d*X+2*a*Z, (b^2-4*a*c)*l*q+(b*d-2*a*e)*l*r-b*X+2*a*Y,(2*c*d^2-2*b*d*e+2*a*e^2)*q*Y^2+(2*b^2*e-8*a*c*e)*q*Y*Z+(-2*b^2*c+8*a*c^2)*q*Z^2+(d*e^2-4*c*d*f)*r*X*Y+(-b*e^2+4*b*c*f)*r*X*Z+(-d^2*e+4*a*e*f)*r*Y^2+(4*c*d^2-2*a*e^2-8*a*c*f)*r*Y*Z+(-4*b*c*d+b^2*e+4*a*c*e)*r*Z^2,(2*c*d-b*e)*q*X+(-b*d+2*a*e)*q*Y+(b^2-4*a*c)*q*Z+(d*e-2*b*f)*r*X+(-d^2+4*a*f)*r*Y+(b*d-2*a*e)*r*Z, e*l*q*X-d*l*q*Y+2*f*l*r*X-d*l*r*Z-X*Z, 2*c*l*q*X-b*l*q*Y+e*l*r*X-b*l*r*Z-X*Y, b*l*q*X-2*a*l*q*Y+d*l*r*X-2*a*l*r*Z-X^2,e*q*X*Y-2*c*q*X*Z-d*q*Y^2+b*q*Y*Z+2*f*r*X*Y-e*r*X*Z-d*r*Y*Z+b*r*Z^2, e*q*X^2-d*q*X*Y-b*q*X*Z+2*a*q*Y*Z+2*f*r*X^2-2*d*r*X*Z+2*a*r*Z^2, 2*c*q*X^2-2*b*q*X*Y+2*a*q*Y^2+e*r*X^2-d*r*X*Y-b*r*X*Z+2*a*r*Y*Z, d*l*p+e*l*q+2*f*l*r-Z,b*l*p+2*c*l*q+e*l*r-Y, 2*a*l*p+b*l*q+d*l*r-X, 2*a*p*Z-e*q*X+d*q*Y+b*q*Z-2*f*r*X+2*d*r*Z, d*p*Y-b*p*Z+e*q*Y-2*c*q*Z+2*f*r*Y-e*r*Z, 2*a*p*Y-2*c*q*X+2*b*q*Y-e*r*X+d*r*Y+b*r*Z, p*X+q*Y+r*Z}}
```

$$(e^2-4cf)X^2+(-2de+4bf)XY+(4cd-2be)XZ+(d^2-4af)Y^2+(-2bd+4ae)YZ+(b^2-4ac)Z^2=0$$

It even gives you via

```
oo // (gens I)
```

the combination of the generators that give this relation:

$$(X-\lambda (2ap+bq+dr))((e^2-4cf)X+(-de+2bf)Y+(2cd-be)Z)\\+(Y-\lambda (bp+2qc+er))((-de+2bf)X+(d^2-4af)Y+(-bd+2ae)Z)\\+(Z-\lambda (dp+eq+2fr))((2cd-be)X+(-bd+2ae)Y+(b^2-4ac)Z)\\ + (pX + qY + rZ)((2cd^2-2bde+2ae^2+2b^2f-8acf)\lambda)$$

Comment: Is the $\lambda$ method even possible? How does that work? Can you show me?

Comment: @A.Hendry: I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please give me the reference for Macaulay2 so I can read it?

Comment: I see Macaulay2 is a software, but I need the to understand the algorithm and math. I need the step-by-step answer. Can you please provide that?

Comment: @A.Hendry Macaulay2 uses Gröbner bases, see e.g. Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms: An Introduction to Computational Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra by David Vassall Cox, John Little, and Donal O'Shea. I can try to do a step by step later.

Comment: Thank you. Does the lambda method use Grobner bases?

Comment: @A.Hendry: No, but for complicated systems like these sometimes you can use them to organize your thoughts.

Comment: Thank you again. Yes please show me the step by step when you can.

Answer (score 0):

I see now. So the *general* quadratic form in the projective plane is

$$
\begin{pmatrix} x & y & z \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & b & d \\ b & c & e \\ d & e & f \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = 0
$$

which yields

$$
ax^2+cy^2+fz^2+2bxy+2dxz+2eyz=0,
$$

but when we restrict ourselves to the affine plane,

$$
\begin{pmatrix} x & y & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & b & d \\ b & c & e \\ d & e & f \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = 0
$$

becomes

$$
ax^2+cy^2+f+2bxy+2dx+2ey=0.
$$

The *adjoint* (signed cofactor matrix) is denoted $A^\Delta$:

$$
\begin{pmatrix} a & b & d \\ b & c & e \\ d & e & f \end{pmatrix} ^ \Delta = \begin{pmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} c & e \\ e & f \end{vmatrix} & - \begin{vmatrix} b & e \\ d & f \end{vmatrix} & + \begin{vmatrix} b & c \\ d & e \end{vmatrix} \\ - \begin{vmatrix} b & d \\ e & f \end{vmatrix} & + \begin{vmatrix} a & d \\ d & f \end{vmatrix} & - \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ d & e \end{vmatrix} \\ + \begin{vmatrix} b & d \\ c & e \end{vmatrix}& - \begin{vmatrix} a & d \\ b & e \end{vmatrix} & + \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{vmatrix} \end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

First multiply through with $a^2b^2$ expand and homogenize the equation:

$$(a^2k^2+b^2h^2-a^2b^2)z^2-2a^2kyz-2b^2hxz+a^2y^2+b^2x^2=0$$

Then the system is

$$\begin{align}X-\lambda (2b^2p-2b^2hr)&=0\\
Y-\lambda (2a^2q-2a^2kr)&=0\\
Z-\lambda (2(a^2k^2+b^2h^2-a^2b^2)r-2a^2kq-2b^2hp)&=0\\
Xp+Yq+Zr&=0\end{align}$$

Solving explicitly is feasible by hand (showing the [Sylvester matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix) of which the resultant is the determinant):

```
resultant(X-l*(2*b^2*p-2*b^2*h*r),Y-l*(2*a^2*q-2*a^2*k*r),p);
```

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2\,a^2\,k
 \,l\,r-2\,a^2\,l\,q+Y\\\end{pmatrix}$$

```
resultant(X-l*(2*b^2*p-2*b^2*h*r),Z-l*(2*(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2-a^2*b^2)*r-2*a^2*k*q-2*b^2*h*p),p);
```

$$\begin{pmatrix} -2\,b^2\,
 l&2\,b^2\,h\,l\,r+X\\ 2\,b^2\,h\,l&\left(
 -2\,a^2\,k^2-2\,b^2\,h^2+2\,a^2\,b^2\right)\,l\,r+2\,a^2\,k\,l\,q+Z
 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

```
resultant(Y-l*(2*a^2*q-2*a^2*k*r),Z-l*(2*(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2-a^2*b^2)*r-2*a^2*k*q-2*b^2*h*p),p);
```

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2\,a^2\,k
 \,l\,r-2\,a^2\,l\,q+Y\\\end{pmatrix}$$

```
resultant(X-l*(2*b^2*p-2*b^2*h*r),X*p+Y*q+Z*r,p);
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}-2\,b^2\,
 l&2\,b^2\,h\,l\,r+X\\ X&Z\,r+Y\,q\\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

```
resultant(Y-l*(2*a^2*q-2*a^2*k*r),X*p+Y*q+Z*r,p);
```

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2\,a^2\,k
 \,l\,r-2\,a^2\,l\,q+Y\\ 
 \end{pmatrix}$$

```
resultant(Z-l*(2*(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2-a^2*b^2)*r-2*a^2*k*q-2*b^2*h*p),X*p+Y*q+Z*r,p);
```

$$\begin{pmatrix} 2\,b^2\,h
 \,l&\left(-2\,a^2\,k^2-2\,b^2\,h^2+2\,a^2\,b^2\right)\,
 l\,r+2\,a^2\,k\,l\,q+Z\\ X&Z\,r+Y\,q\\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Among these choose two and take resultant w.r.t $q$

```
resultant((2*X*a^2*k^2+2*X*b^2*h^2+2*Z*b^2*h-2*X*a^2*b^2)*l*r+(2*Y*b^2*h-2*X*a^2*k)*l*q-X*Z,2*a^2*k*l*r-2*a^2*l*q+Y,q);
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}\left(2\,
 Y\,b^2\,h-2\,X\,a^2\,k\right)\,l&\left(2\,X\,a^2\,k^2+2
 \,X\,b^2\,h^2+2\,Z\,b^2\,h-2\,X\,a^2\,b^2\right)\,l\,r-X\,Z\\ -2\,a
 ^2\,l&2\,a^2\,k\,l\,r+Y\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

```
resultant((-(2*X*b^2*h+2*Z*b^2)*l*r)-2*Y*b^2*l*q-X^2,2*a^2*k*l*r-2*a^2*l*q+Y,q);
```

$$\begin{pmatrix} -2\,Y\,b^
 2\,l&\left(-2\,X\,b^2\,h-2\,Z\,b^2\right)\,l\,r-X^2\cr 
 -2\,a^2\,l&2\,a^2\,k\,l\,r+Y\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Finally the resultant w.r.t $r$

```
resultant(2*l*((2*Y*a^2*b^2*h*k+2*X*a^2*b^2*h^2+2*Z*a^2*b^2*h-2*X*a^4*b^2)*l*r-X*Y*a^2*k+Y^2*b^2*h-X*Z*a^2),-2*l*((b^2*(2*Y*a^2*k+2*Z*a^2)+2*X*a^2*b^2*h)*l*r+Y^2*b^2+X^2*a^2),r);
```

$$\begin{pmatrix} \left(4\,
 Y\,a^2\,b^2\,h\,k+4\,X\,a^2\,b^2\,h^2+4\,Z\,a^2\,b^2\,h-4\,X\,a^4\,b
 ^2\right)\,l^2&\left(-2\,X\,Y\,a^2\,k+2\,Y^2\,b^2\,h-2
 \,X\,Z\,a^2\right)\,l\cr \left(-4\,Y\,a^2\,b^2\,k-4\,X\,a^2\,b^2\,h-
 4\,Z\,a^2\,b^2\right)\,l^2&\left(-2\,Y^2\,b^2-2\,X^2\,a
 ^2\right)\,l\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

```
factor(%);
-8*X*a^4*b^2*(Y^2*k^2+2*X*Y*h*k+2*Y*Z*k+X^2*h^2+2*X*Z*h-Y^2*b^2-X^2*a^2+Z^2)*l^3
```

i.e. $Y^2k^2+2XYhk+2YZk+X^2h^2+2XZh-Y^2b^2-X^2a^2+Z^2=0.$

or in one fell swoop using the maxima CAS function `eliminate`

```
eliminate([X-l*(2*b^2*p-2*b^2*h*r),Y-l*(2*a^2*q-2*a^2*k*r),Z-l*(2*(a^2*k^2+b^2*h^2-a^2*b^2)*r-2*a^2*k*q-2*b^2*h*p),X*p+Y*q+Z*r],[p,q,r]);
[-16*Y*a^2*b^6*(Y^2*k^2+2*X*Y*h*k+2*Y*Z*k+X^2*h^2+2*X*Z*h-Y^2*b^2-X^2*a^2+Z^2)*l^4]
```

Setting $Z=1$ we have the dual by the equation in the standard affine in the dual projective plane

$$(h^2-a^2)X^2+2hkXY+(k^2-b^2)Y^2+2hX+2kY+1=0.$$

Comment: Thank you! Why does the conic need to be homogenized for the lambda method to work, but not need to be homogenized for the matrix method to work?

Comment: @A.Hendry: The coefficient matrix is the same whether you homogenize or not. Projective duality as its name suggests works on the homogeneous coordinate level. The point line correspondence of classical projective geometry extends to curves (and even varieties) with the dual curve parametrizing the tangents. The duality is global, but works in the open sets $z=1$ in the projective plane and corresponding open $Z=1$ in the projective dual plane because $xX+yY+zZ=0$ specializes to $xX+yY+1=0.$

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct. And I had forgotten we set $z=1$ in the conic equation in the accepted answer, so it was in fact already homogeneous, just "disguised".

Comment: I have a follow-up question. I'll create a new question for this.

Comment: My follow-up question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4067481/groebner-basis-in-macaulay2)