# General Equations for Common Tangents to Two Ellipses

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, maxima-software, macaulay2

This is a follow-up from one of my earlier questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4067481/groebner-basis-in-macaulay2). I am attempting to find the general equation for common tangents to two ellipses:

$$  
\left\{  
\begin{array}{c}  
\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}-1=0  \\
\frac{(x-p)^2}{c^2}+\frac{(y-q)^2}{d^2}-1=0  \\
\end{array}  
\right.  
\tag{1}  
$$

However, the `solve` function of Maxima CAS does not give me an answer (it just runs and hangs). Am I doing something wrong, or is there no answer?

**Method:**

To solve, first we find the dual curves in line coordinates for the equations in $(1)$, which requires converting each to standard form and homogenizing

$$  
\left\{  
\begin{array}{c}  
f_1(x,y,z)=b^2x^2+a^2y^2-2(hb^2x+ka^2y)z+(h^2b^2+k^2a^2-a^2b^2)z^2=0  \\
f_2(x,y,z)=d^2x^2+c^2y^2-2(pd^2x+qc^2y)z+(p^2d^2+q^2c^2-c^2d^2)z^2=0  \\
\end{array}  
\right.  
\tag{2}  
$$

and then recognizing that since

1. the equation of a line in (homogeneous) line coordinates is $g(x,y,z)=Xx+Yy+Zz=0$, and
2. the tangent to a curve $f$ at a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is given by $f'(x_0,y_0,z_0)=f_x(x_0,y_0,z_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0,z_0)+f_z(x_0,y_0,z_0)$

finding dual curves amounts to solving an optimization problem subject to a constraint via the method of Lagrangian multipliers

$$
\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g  \\
g = 0.
$$

At point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, this becomes

$$
f_x(x_0,y_0,z_0) = \lambda X  \\
f_y(x_0,y_0,z_0) = \lambda Y  \\
f_z(x_0,y_0,z_0) = \lambda Z  \\
Xx_0+Yy_0+Zz_0=0.
$$

(NOTE: *In truth, $\lambda$ can go on either side without loss of generality since it is a proportionality constant we wish to eliminate.*)

Solving the above yields our dual curves $F_1$ and $F_2$

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
F_1(X,Y) = (h^2-a^2)X^2 + (2hk)XY + (k^2-b^2)Y^2 + 2hX + 2kY + 1 = 0  \\
F_2(X,Y) = (p^2-c^2)X^2 + (2pq)XY + (q^2-d^2)Y^2 + 2pX + 2qY + 1 = 0  \\
\end{array}
\right.
\tag{3}
$$

Second, we must find the line of incidence (i.e. the "point of intersection") of the system (3), which amounts to solving the system for $X$ and $Y$. Since this is a multivariate polynomial system, we can compute the reduced Gröbner bases of the l-elimination ideals of the ideal $I=<F_1,F_2>$ generated by $F_1$ and $F_2$ to solve.

Let $K=\mathbb Q [a,b,c,d,h,k,p,q]$, which is algebraically closed, and $R = K[x,y]$ be a polynomial ring under pure lex monomial ordering. Since $R$ is Noetherian by the Hilbert Basis Theorem (i.e. $R$ is finitely generated), the varieties $V(I)$ are affine (i.e. finite and equal to the varieties of the generators of $I$).

Using Macaulay2, the generators of the Gröbner basis of $I$ are found via

```
i1 : R = QQ[a,b,c,d,h,k,p,q];

i2 : S = R[x, y, MonomialOrder=>Lex];

i3 : I = ideal((h^2-a^2)*x^2 + (2*h*k)*x*y + (k^2-b^2)*y^2 + 2*h*x + 2*k*y + 1, (p^2-c^2)*x^2 + (2*p*q)*x*y + (q^2-d^2)*y^2 + 2p*x + 2*q*y + 1);

i4 : G = gb I;

i5 : toString gens G
```

which yields a large $1 X 10$ matrix. The first elimination ideal, $G_1$, is the first entry of $G$, which is a quartic in $y$ alone. Since there are two variables in our problem, there is no second elimination ideal (it is the empty set).

Since the leading coefficients of $x$ in the other 9 entries in $G-G_1$ are constants (they do not involve $y$), the Elimination Theorem guarantees we should be able to extend our solution for $y$.

**Problem:**

Attempting to solve $G_1$ with any of the other entries of $G-G_1$ using `solve` in Maxima CAS does not give a solution. Here is my code (I call the first entry of $G-G_1$ the variable $H$):

```
(%i1) G1 : (b^4*c^4-2*a^2*b^2*c^2*d^2+a^4*d^4+2*b^2*c^2*d^2*h^2-2*a^2*d^4*h^2+d^4*h^4-2*b^2*c^4*k^2+2*a^2*c^2*d^2*k^2+2*c^2*d^2*h^2*k^2+c^4*k^4-2*b^4*c^2*p^2+2*a^2*b^2*d^2*p^2-2*b^2*d^2*h^2*p^2+4*b^2*c^2*k^2*p^2-2*a^2*d^2*k^2*p^2-2*d^2*h^2*k^2*p^2-2*c^2*k^4*p^2+b^4*p^4-2*b^2*k^2*p^4+k^4*p^4-4*b^2*c^2*h*k*p*q-4*a^2*d^2*h*k*p*q+4*d^2*h^3*k*p*q+4*c^2*h*k^3*p*q+4*b^2*h*k*p^3*q-4*h*k^3*p^3*q+2*a^2*b^2*c^2*q^2-2*a^4*d^2*q^2-2*b^2*c^2*h^2*q^2+4*a^2*d^2*h^2*q^2-2*d^2*h^4*q^2-2*a^2*c^2*k^2*q^2-2*c^2*h^2*k^2*q^2+2*a^2*b^2*p^2*q^2-2*b^2*h^2*p^2*q^2-2*a^2*k^2*p^2*q^2+6*h^2*k^2*p^2*q^2+4*a^2*h*k*p*q^3-4*h^3*k*p*q^3+a^4*q^4-2*a^2*h^2*q^4+h^4*q^4)*y^4+(-4*b^2*c^4*k+4*a^2*c^2*d^2*k+4*c^2*d^2*h^2*k+4*c^4*k^3-4*b^2*c^2*h*k*p-4*a^2*d^2*h*k*p+4*d^2*h^3*k*p+4*c^2*h*k^3*p+8*b^2*c^2*k*p^2-4*a^2*d^2*k*p^2-4*d^2*h^2*k*p^2-8*c^2*k^3*p^2+4*b^2*h*k*p^3-4*h*k^3*p^3-4*b^2*k*p^4+4*k^3*p^4+4*a^2*b^2*c^2*q-4*a^4*d^2*q-4*b^2*c^2*h^2*q+8*a^2*d^2*h^2*q-4*d^2*h^4*q-4*a^2*c^2*k^2*q-4*c^2*h^2*k^2*q-4*b^2*c^2*h*p*q-4*a^2*d^2*h*p*q+4*d^2*h^3*p*q+12*c^2*h*k^2*p*q+4*a^2*b^2*p^2*q-4*b^2*h^2*p^2*q-4*a^2*k^2*p^2*q+12*h^2*k^2*p^2*q+4*b^2*h*p^3*q-12*h*k^2*p^3*q-4*a^2*c^2*k*q^2-4*c^2*h^2*k*q^2+12*a^2*h*k*p*q^2-12*h^3*k*p*q^2-4*a^2*k*p^2*q^2+12*h^2*k*p^2*q^2+4*a^4*q^3-8*a^2*h^2*q^3+4*h^4*q^3+4*a^2*h*p*q^3-4*h^3*p*q^3)*y^3+(2*a^2*b^2*c^2-2*b^2*c^4-2*a^4*d^2+2*a^2*c^2*d^2-2*b^2*c^2*h^2+4*a^2*d^2*h^2+2*c^2*d^2*h^2-2*d^2*h^4-2*a^2*c^2*k^2+6*c^4*k^2-2*c^2*h^2*k^2-4*b^2*c^2*h*p-4*a^2*d^2*h*p+4*d^2*h^3*p+12*c^2*h*k^2*p+2*a^2*b^2*p^2+4*b^2*c^2*p^2-2*a^2*d^2*p^2-2*b^2*h^2*p^2-2*d^2*h^2*p^2-2*a^2*k^2*p^2-12*c^2*k^2*p^2+6*h^2*k^2*p^2+4*b^2*h*p^3-12*h*k^2*p^3-2*b^2*p^4+6*k^2*p^4-8*a^2*c^2*k*q-8*c^2*h^2*k*q+12*a^2*h*k*p*q+12*c^2*h*k*p*q-12*h^3*k*p*q-8*a^2*k*p^2*q+24*h^2*k*p^2*q-12*h*k*p^3*q+6*a^4*q^2-2*a^2*c^2*q^2-12*a^2*h^2*q^2-2*c^2*h^2*q^2+6*h^4*q^2+12*a^2*h*p*q^2-12*h^3*p*q^2-2*a^2*p^2*q^2+6*h^2*p^2*q^2)*y^2+(-4*a^2*c^2*k+4*c^4*k-4*c^2*h^2*k+4*a^2*h*k*p+12*c^2*h*k*p-4*h^3*k*p-4*a^2*k*p^2-8*c^2*k*p^2+12*h^2*k*p^2-12*h*k*p^3+4*k*p^4+4*a^4*q-4*a^2*c^2*q-8*a^2*h^2*q-4*c^2*h^2*q+4*h^4*q+12*a^2*h*p*q+4*c^2*h*p*q-12*h^3*p*q-4*a^2*p^2*q+12*h^2*p^2*q-4*h*p^3*q)*y+a^4-2*a^2*c^2+c^4-2*a^2*h^2-2*c^2*h^2+h^4+4*a^2*h*p+4*c^2*h*p-4*h^3*p-2*a^2*p^2-2*c^2*p^2+6*h^2*p^2-4*h*p^3+p^4$

(%i2) H : (2*b^2*c^6*h^2-2*a^2*c^4*d^2*h^2+2*c^4*d^2*h^4+2*a^2*c^4*h^2*k^2-2*c^4*h^4*k^2-4*a^2*b^2*c^4*h*p+4*a^4*c^2*d^2*h*p+4*b^2*c^4*h^3*p-8*a^2*c^2*d^2*h^3*p+4*c^2*d^2*h^5*p+2*a^4*b^2*c^2*p^2-2*a^6*d^2*p^2-4*a^2*b^2*c^2*h^2*p^2-6*b^2*c^4*h^2*p^2+6*a^4*d^2*h^2*p^2+4*a^2*c^2*d^2*h^2*p^2+2*b^2*c^2*h^4*p^2-6*a^2*d^2*h^4*p^2-4*c^2*d^2*h^4*p^2+2*d^2*h^6*p^2-2*a^4*c^2*k^2*p^2+2*c^2*h^4*k^2*p^2+8*a^2*b^2*c^2*h*p^3-4*a^4*d^2*h*p^3-8*b^2*c^2*h^3*p^3+8*a^2*d^2*h^3*p^3-4*d^2*h^5*p^3-2*a^4*b^2*p^4+4*a^2*b^2*h^2*p^4+6*b^2*c^2*h^2*p^4-2*a^2*d^2*h^2*p^4-2*b^2*h^4*p^4+2*d^2*h^4*p^4+2*a^4*k^2*p^4-2*a^2*h^2*k^2*p^4-4*a^2*b^2*h*p^5+4*b^2*h^3*p^5-2*b^2*h^2*p^6-4*a^2*c^4*h^2*k*q+4*c^4*h^4*k*q+4*a^4*c^2*k*p^2*q-4*c^2*h^4*k*p^2*q-4*a^4*k*p^4*q+4*a^2*h^2*k*p^4*q+2*a^2*c^4*h^2*q^2-2*c^4*h^4*q^2-2*a^4*c^2*p^2*q^2+2*c^2*h^4*p^2*q^2+2*a^4*p^4*q^2-2*a^2*h^2*p^4*q^2)*x+(b^4*c^6*h*k-2*a^2*b^2*c^4*d^2*h*k+a^4*c^2*d^4*h*k+2*b^2*c^4*d^2*h^3*k-2*a^2*c^2*d^4*h^3*k+c^2*d^4*h^5*k-2*b^2*c^6*h*k^3+2*a^2*c^4*d^2*h*k^3+2*c^4*d^2*h^3*k^3+c^6*h*k^5-3*b^4*c^4*h*k*p^2+4*a^2*b^2*c^2*d^2*h*k*p^2-a^4*d^4*h*k*p^2-4*b^2*c^2*d^2*h^3*k*p^2+2*a^2*d^4*h^3*k*p^2-d^4*h^5*k*p^2+6*b^2*c^4*h*k^3*p^2-4*a^2*c^2*d^2*h*k^3*p^2-4*c^2*d^2*h^3*k^3*p^2-3*c^4*h*k^5*p^2+3*b^4*c^2*h*k*p^4-2*a^2*b^2*d^2*h*k*p^4+2*b^2*d^2*h^3*k*p^4-6*b^2*c^2*h*k^3*p^4+2*a^2*d^2*h*k^3*p^4+2*d^2*h^3*k^3*p^4+3*c^2*h*k^5*p^4-b^4*h*k*p^6+2*b^2*h*k^3*p^6-h*k^5*p^6-a^2*b^4*c^4*p*q+2*a^4*b^2*c^2*d^2*p*q-a^6*d^4*p*q+b^4*c^4*h^2*p*q-4*a^2*b^2*c^2*d^2*h^2*p*q+3*a^4*d^4*h^2*p*q+2*b^2*c^2*d^2*h^4*p*q-3*a^2*d^4*h^4*p*q+d^4*h^6*p*q+2*a^2*b^2*c^4*k^2*p*q-2*a^4*c^2*d^2*k^2*p*q-6*b^2*c^4*h^2*k^2*p*q-4*a^2*c^2*d^2*h^2*k^2*p*q+6*c^2*d^2*h^4*k^2*p*q-a^2*c^4*k^4*p*q+5*c^4*h^2*k^4*p*q+2*a^2*b^4*c^2*p^3*q-2*a^4*b^2*d^2*p^3*q-2*b^4*c^2*h^2*p^3*q+4*a^2*b^2*d^2*h^2*p^3*q-2*b^2*d^2*h^4*p^3*q-4*a^2*b^2*c^2*k^2*p^3*q+2*a^4*d^2*k^2*p^3*q+12*b^2*c^2*h^2*k^2*p^3*q+4*a^2*d^2*h^2*k^2*p^3*q-6*d^2*h^4*k^2*p^3*q+2*a^2*c^2*k^4*p^3*q-10*c^2*h^2*k^4*p^3*q-a^2*b^4*p^5*q+b^4*h^2*p^5*q+2*a^2*b^2*k^2*p^5*q-6*b^2*h^2*k^2*p^5*q-a^2*k^4*p^5*q+5*h^2*k^4*p^5*q+2*a^2*b^2*c^4*h*k*q^2-2*a^4*c^2*d^2*h*k*q^2-2*b^2*c^4*h^3*k*q^2+4*a^2*c^2*d^2*h^3*k*q^2-2*c^2*d^2*h^5*k*q^2-2*a^2*c^4*h*k^3*q^2-2*c^4*h^3*k^3*q^2+4*a^2*b^2*c^2*h*k*p^2*q^2+6*a^4*d^2*h*k*p^2*q^2-4*b^2*c^2*h^3*k*p^2*q^2-12*a^2*d^2*h^3*k*p^2*q^2+6*d^2*h^5*k*p^2*q^2-4*a^2*c^2*h*k^3*p^2*q^2+12*c^2*h^3*k^3*p^2*q^2-6*a^2*b^2*h*k*p^4*q^2+6*b^2*h^3*k*p^4*q^2+6*a^2*h*k^3*p^4*q^2-10*h^3*k^3*p^4*q^2-2*a^4*b^2*c^2*p*q^3+2*a^6*d^2*p*q^3+4*a^2*b^2*c^2*h^2*p*q^3-6*a^4*d^2*h^2*p*q^3-2*b^2*c^2*h^4*p*q^3+6*a^2*d^2*h^4*p*q^3-2*d^2*h^6*p*q^3+2*a^4*c^2*k^2*p*q^3+4*a^2*c^2*h^2*k^2*p*q^3-6*c^2*h^4*k^2*p*q^3-2*a^4*b^2*p^3*q^3+4*a^2*b^2*h^2*p^3*q^3-2*b^2*h^4*p^3*q^3+2*a^4*k^2*p^3*q^3-12*a^2*h^2*k^2*p^3*q^3+10*h^4*k^2*p^3*q^3+a^4*c^2*h*k*q^4-2*a^2*c^2*h^3*k*q^4+c^2*h^5*k*q^4-5*a^4*h*k*p^2*q^4+10*a^2*h^3*k*p^2*q^4-5*h^5*k*p^2*q^4-a^6*p*q^5+3*a^4*h^2*p*q^5-3*a^2*h^4*p*q^5+h^6*p*q^5)*y^3+(-b^4*c^6*h+2*a^2*b^2*c^4*d^2*h-a^4*c^2*d^4*h-2*b^2*c^4*d^2*h^3+2*a^2*c^2*d^4*h^3-c^2*d^4*h^5-2*b^2*c^6*h*k^2+2*a^2*c^4*d^2*h*k^2+2*c^4*d^2*h^3*k^2+3*c^6*h*k^4+a^2*b^4*c^4*p-2*a^4*b^2*c^2*d^2*p+a^6*d^4*p-b^4*c^4*h^2*p+4*a^2*b^2*c^2*d^2*h^2*p-3*a^4*d^4*h^2*p-2*b^2*c^2*d^2*h^4*p+3*a^2*d^4*h^4*p-d^4*h^6*p-2*a^2*b^2*c^4*k^2*p+2*a^4*c^2*d^2*k^2*p-2*b^2*c^4*h^2*k^2*p-4*a^2*c^2*d^2*h^2*k^2*p+2*c^2*d^2*h^4*k^2*p+a^2*c^4*k^4*p+3*c^4*h^2*k^4*p+3*b^4*c^4*h*p^2-4*a^2*b^2*c^2*d^2*h*p^2+a^4*d^4*h*p^2+4*b^2*c^2*d^2*h^3*p^2-2*a^2*d^4*h^3*p^2+d^4*h^5*p^2+6*b^2*c^4*h*k^2*p^2-4*a^2*c^2*d^2*h*k^2*p^2-4*c^2*d^2*h^3*k^2*p^2-9*c^4*h*k^4*p^2-2*a^2*b^4*c^2*p^3+2*a^4*b^2*d^2*p^3+2*b^4*c^2*h^2*p^3-4*a^2*b^2*d^2*h^2*p^3+2*b^2*d^2*h^4*p^3+4*a^2*b^2*c^2*k^2*p^3-2*a^4*d^2*k^2*p^3+4*b^2*c^2*h^2*k^2*p^3+4*a^2*d^2*h^2*k^2*p^3-2*d^2*h^4*k^2*p^3-2*a^2*c^2*k^4*p^3-6*c^2*h^2*k^4*p^3-3*b^4*c^2*h*p^4+2*a^2*b^2*d^2*h*p^4-2*b^2*d^2*h^3*p^4-6*b^2*c^2*h*k^2*p^4+2*a^2*d^2*h*k^2*p^4+2*d^2*h^3*k^2*p^4+9*c^2*h*k^4*p^4+a^2*b^4*p^5-b^4*h^2*p^5-2*a^2*b^2*k^2*p^5-2*b^2*h^2*k^2*p^5+a^2*k^4*p^5+3*h^2*k^4*p^5+b^4*h*p^6+2*b^2*h*k^2*p^6-3*h*k^4*p^6+4*a^2*b^2*c^4*h*k*q-4*a^4*c^2*d^2*h*k*q-4*b^2*c^4*h^3*k*q+8*a^2*c^2*d^2*h^3*k*q-4*c^2*d^2*h^5*k*q-4*a^2*c^4*h*k^3*q-4*c^4*h^3*k^3*q+4*a^2*b^2*c^4*k*p*q-4*a^4*c^2*d^2*k*p*q-4*b^2*c^4*h^2*k*p*q+4*c^2*d^2*h^4*k*p*q-4*a^2*c^4*k^3*p*q+12*c^4*h^2*k^3*p*q+4*a^4*d^2*h*k*p^2*q-8*a^2*d^2*h^3*k*p^2*q+4*d^2*h^5*k*p^2*q+16*c^2*h^3*k^3*p^2*q-8*a^2*b^2*c^2*k*p^3*q+4*a^4*d^2*k*p^3*q+8*b^2*c^2*h^2*k*p^3*q-4*d^2*h^4*k*p^3*q+8*a^2*c^2*k^3*p^3*q-24*c^2*h^2*k^3*p^3*q-4*a^2*b^2*h*k*p^4*q+4*b^2*h^3*k*p^4*q+4*a^2*h*k^3*p^4*q-12*h^3*k^3*p^4*q+4*a^2*b^2*k*p^5*q-4*b^2*h^2*k*p^5*q-4*a^2*k^3*p^5*q+12*h^2*k^3*p^5*q-2*a^2*b^2*c^4*h*q^2+2*a^4*c^2*d^2*h*q^2+2*b^2*c^4*h^3*q^2-4*a^2*c^2*d^2*h^3*q^2+2*c^2*d^2*h^5*q^2-2*a^2*c^4*h*k^2*q^2-2*c^4*h^3*k^2*q^2-2*a^4*b^2*c^2*p*q^2+2*a^6*d^2*p*q^2+4*a^2*b^2*c^2*h^2*p*q^2-6*a^4*d^2*h^2*p*q^2-2*b^2*c^2*h^4*p*q^2+6*a^2*d^2*h^4*p*q^2-2*d^2*h^6*p*q^2+2*a^4*c^2*k^2*p*q^2+12*a^2*c^2*h^2*k^2*p*q^2-14*c^2*h^4*k^2*p*q^2+4*a^2*b^2*c^2*h*p^2*q^2+2*a^4*d^2*h*p^2*q^2-4*b^2*c^2*h^3*p^2*q^2-4*a^2*d^2*h^3*p^2*q^2+2*d^2*h^5*p^2*q^2-12*a^2*c^2*h*k^2*p^2*q^2+20*c^2*h^3*k^2*p^2*q^2-2*a^4*b^2*p^3*q^2+4*a^2*b^2*h^2*p^3*q^2-2*b^2*h^4*p^3*q^2+2*a^4*k^2*p^3*q^2-20*a^2*h^2*k^2*p^3*q^2+18*h^4*k^2*p^3*q^2-2*a^2*b^2*h*p^4*q^2+2*b^2*h^3*p^4*q^2+14*a^2*h*k^2*p^4*q^2-18*h^3*k^2*p^4*q^2+4*a^4*c^2*h*k*q^3-8*a^2*c^2*h^3*k*q^3+4*c^2*h^5*k*q^3+4*a^4*c^2*k*p*q^3-4*c^2*h^4*k*p*q^3-12*a^4*h*k*p^2*q^3+24*a^2*h^3*k*p^2*q^3-12*h^5*k*p^2*q^3+4*a^4*k*p^3*q^3-16*a^2*h^2*k*p^3*q^3+12*h^4*k*p^3*q^3-a^4*c^2*h*q^4+2*a^2*c^2*h^3*q^4-c^2*h^5*q^4-3*a^6*p*q^4+9*a^4*h^2*p*q^4-9*a^2*h^4*p*q^4+3*h^6*p*q^4-3*a^4*h*p^2*q^4+6*a^2*h^3*p^2*q^4-3*h^5*p^2*q^4)*y^2+(a^2*b^2*c^4*h*k+b^2*c^6*h*k-a^4*c^2*d^2*h*k-a^2*c^4*d^2*h*k-b^2*c^4*h^3*k+2*a^2*c^2*d^2*h^3*k+c^4*d^2*h^3*k-c^2*d^2*h^5*k-a^2*c^4*h*k^3+3*c^6*h*k^3-3*c^4*h^3*k^3-2*a^2*b^2*c^4*k*p+2*a^4*c^2*d^2*k*p+2*b^2*c^4*h^2*k*p-4*a^2*c^2*d^2*h^2*k*p+2*c^2*d^2*h^4*k*p+2*a^2*c^4*k^3*p+6*c^4*h^2*k^3*p-2*a^2*b^2*c^2*h*k*p^2-3*b^2*c^4*h*k*p^2+a^4*d^2*h*k*p^2+2*a^2*c^2*d^2*h*k*p^2+2*b^2*c^2*h^3*k*p^2-2*a^2*d^2*h^3*k*p^2-2*c^2*d^2*h^3*k*p^2+d^2*h^5*k*p^2+2*a^2*c^2*h*k^3*p^2-9*c^4*h*k^3*p^2+6*c^2*h^3*k^3*p^2+4*a^2*b^2*c^2*k*p^3-2*a^4*d^2*k*p^3-4*b^2*c^2*h^2*k*p^3+4*a^2*d^2*h^2*k*p^3-2*d^2*h^4*k*p^3-4*a^2*c^2*k^3*p^3-12*c^2*h^2*k^3*p^3+a^2*b^2*h*k*p^4+3*b^2*c^2*h*k*p^4-a^2*d^2*h*k*p^4-b^2*h^3*k*p^4+d^2*h^3*k*p^4-a^2*h*k^3*p^4+9*c^2*h*k^3*p^4-3*h^3*k^3*p^4-2*a^2*b^2*k*p^5+2*b^2*h^2*k*p^5+2*a^2*k^3*p^5+6*h^2*k^3*p^5-b^2*h*k*p^6-3*h*k^3*p^6-2*a^2*b^2*c^4*h*q+2*a^4*c^2*d^2*h*q+2*b^2*c^4*h^3*q-4*a^2*c^2*d^2*h^3*q+2*c^2*d^2*h^5*q-6*a^2*c^4*h*k^2*q-2*c^4*h^3*k^2*q+a^4*b^2*c^2*p*q+a^2*b^2*c^4*p*q-a^6*d^2*p*q-a^4*c^2*d^2*p*q-2*a^2*b^2*c^2*h^2*p*q-b^2*c^4*h^2*p*q+3*a^4*d^2*h^2*p*q+2*a^2*c^2*d^2*h^2*p*q+b^2*c^2*h^4*p*q-3*a^2*d^2*h^4*p*q-c^2*d^2*h^4*p*q+d^2*h^6*p*q-a^4*c^2*k^2*p*q-5*a^2*c^4*k^2*p*q+10*a^2*c^2*h^2*k^2*p*q+9*c^4*h^2*k^2*p*q-9*c^2*h^4*k^2*p*q+4*a^2*b^2*c^2*h*p^2*q-2*a^4*d^2*h*p^2*q-4*b^2*c^2*h^3*p^2*q+4*a^2*d^2*h^3*p^2*q-2*d^2*h^5*p^2*q-4*a^2*c^2*h*k^2*p^2*q+20*c^2*h^3*k^2*p^2*q-a^4*b^2*p^3*q-2*a^2*b^2*c^2*p^3*q+a^4*d^2*p^3*q+2*a^2*b^2*h^2*p^3*q+2*b^2*c^2*h^2*p^3*q-2*a^2*d^2*h^2*p^3*q-b^2*h^4*p^3*q+d^2*h^4*p^3*q+a^4*k^2*p^3*q+10*a^2*c^2*k^2*p^3*q-10*a^2*h^2*k^2*p^3*q-18*c^2*h^2*k^2*p^3*q+9*h^4*k^2*p^3*q-2*a^2*b^2*h*p^4*q+2*b^2*h^3*p^4*q+10*a^2*h*k^2*p^4*q-18*h^3*k^2*p^4*q+a^2*b^2*p^5*q-b^2*h^2*p^5*q-5*a^2*k^2*p^5*q+9*h^2*k^2*p^5*q+5*a^4*c^2*h*k*q^2+a^2*c^4*h*k*q^2-10*a^2*c^2*h^3*k*q^2-c^4*h^3*k*q^2+5*c^2*h^5*k*q^2+6*a^4*c^2*k*p*q^2+4*a^2*c^2*h^2*k*p*q^2-10*c^2*h^4*k*p*q^2-9*a^4*h*k*p^2*q^2-10*a^2*c^2*h*k*p^2*q^2+18*a^2*h^3*k*p^2*q^2+10*c^2*h^3*k*p^2*q^2-9*h^5*k*p^2*q^2+2*a^4*k*p^3*q^2-20*a^2*h^2*k*p^3*q^2+18*h^4*k*p^3*q^2+9*a^2*h*k*p^4*q^2-9*h^3*k*p^4*q^2-2*a^4*c^2*h*q^3+4*a^2*c^2*h^3*q^3-2*c^2*h^5*q^3-3*a^6*p*q^3+a^4*c^2*p*q^3+9*a^4*h^2*p*q^3-2*a^2*c^2*h^2*p*q^3-9*a^2*h^4*p*q^3+c^2*h^4*p*q^3+3*h^6*p*q^3-6*a^4*h*p^2*q^3+12*a^2*h^3*p^2*q^3-6*h^5*p^2*q^3+3*a^4*p^3*q^3-6*a^2*h^2*p^3*q^3+3*h^4*p^3*q^3)*y-a^2*b^2*c^4*h+b^2*c^6*h+a^4*c^2*d^2*h-a^2*c^4*d^2*h+b^2*c^4*h^3-2*a^2*c^2*d^2*h^3+c^4*d^2*h^3+c^2*d^2*h^5-a^2*c^4*h*k^2+c^6*h*k^2-3*c^4*h^3*k^2+a^4*b^2*c^2*p-a^2*b^2*c^4*p-a^6*d^2*p+a^4*c^2*d^2*p-2*a^2*b^2*c^2*h^2*p+b^2*c^4*h^2*p+3*a^4*d^2*h^2*p-2*a^2*c^2*d^2*h^2*p+b^2*c^2*h^4*p-3*a^2*d^2*h^4*p+c^2*d^2*h^4*p+d^2*h^6*p-a^4*c^2*k^2*p+a^2*c^4*k^2*p+2*a^2*c^2*h^2*k^2*p+3*c^4*h^2*k^2*p-c^2*h^4*k^2*p+2*a^2*b^2*c^2*h*p^2-3*b^2*c^4*h*p^2-a^4*d^2*h*p^2+2*a^2*c^2*d^2*h*p^2-2*b^2*c^2*h^3*p^2+2*a^2*d^2*h^3*p^2-2*c^2*d^2*h^3*p^2-d^2*h^5*p^2+2*a^2*c^2*h*k^2*p^2-3*c^4*h*k^2*p^2+6*c^2*h^3*k^2*p^2-a^4*b^2*p^3+2*a^2*b^2*c^2*p^3-a^4*d^2*p^3+2*a^2*b^2*h^2*p^3-2*b^2*c^2*h^2*p^3+2*a^2*d^2*h^2*p^3-b^2*h^4*p^3-d^2*h^4*p^3+a^4*k^2*p^3-2*a^2*c^2*k^2*p^3-2*a^2*h^2*k^2*p^3-6*c^2*h^2*k^2*p^3+h^4*k^2*p^3-a^2*b^2*h*p^4+3*b^2*c^2*h*p^4-a^2*d^2*h*p^4+b^2*h^3*p^4+d^2*h^3*p^4-a^2*h*k^2*p^4+3*c^2*h*k^2*p^4-3*h^3*k^2*p^4-a^2*b^2*p^5+b^2*h^2*p^5+a^2*k^2*p^5+3*h^2*k^2*p^5-b^2*h*p^6-h*k^2*p^6+2*a^4*c^2*h*k*q-2*a^2*c^4*h*k*q-4*a^2*c^2*h^3*k*q+2*c^4*h^3*k*q+2*c^2*h^5*k*q+2*a^4*c^2*k*p*q-2*a^2*c^4*k*p*q+4*a^2*c^2*h^2*k*p*q+2*c^4*h^2*k*p*q-6*c^2*h^4*k*p*q-2*a^4*h*k*p^2*q-4*a^2*c^2*h*k*p^2*q+4*a^2*h^3*k*p^2*q+4*c^2*h^3*k*p^2*q-2*h^5*k*p^2*q-2*a^4*k*p^3*q+4*a^2*c^2*k*p^3*q-4*a^2*h^2*k*p^3*q-4*c^2*h^2*k*p^3*q+6*h^4*k*p^3*q+6*a^2*h*k*p^4*q-6*h^3*k*p^4*q-2*a^2*k*p^5*q+2*h^2*k*p^5*q-a^4*c^2*h*q^2+a^2*c^4*h*q^2+2*a^2*c^2*h^3*q^2-c^4*h^3*q^2-c^2*h^5*q^2-a^6*p*q^2+a^4*c^2*p*q^2+3*a^4*h^2*p*q^2-2*a^2*c^2*h^2*p*q^2-3*a^2*h^4*p*q^2+c^2*h^4*p*q^2+h^6*p*q^2-3*a^4*h*p^2*q^2-2*a^2*c^2*h*p^2*q^2+6*a^2*h^3*p^2*q^2+2*c^2*h^3*p^2*q^2-3*h^5*p^2*q^2+3*a^4*p^3*q^2-6*a^2*h^2*p^3*q^2+3*h^4*p^3*q^2+a^2*h*p^4*q^2-h^3*p^4*q^2$

(%i3) solve([G1,H],[x,y]);
```

Comment: See another post using dual conics [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3436714/algorithm-to-find-common-tangent-to-any-two-conics).

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to derive the GENERAL equations. Maxima will not solve the general system as I've written it above (i.e. `solve([G1,H],[x,y]);`). Does Maxima work for you with that system?

Comment: I use *Geogebra* graphically or *Mathematica* symbolically.  I have no ideas for using *Maxima* here.

Comment: Does Mathematica give a result for the system above? Can you share that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why Maxima CAS won't solve, but [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668231/preferred-means-for-finding-common-tangent-to-a-pair-of-ellipses-in-c) provides a simpler method for finding common tangents.

From [Perspectives on Projective Geometry by Jürgen Richter-Gebert](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-17286-1) (credit to @Jan-MagnusØkland for this insight):

> A conic consists of all points p that satisfy an equation $p^TAp = 0.$ The set
> of all tangents to this conic can be described as $\{Ap | p^TAp = 0\}.$

The proof is that since $\forall p,q \in \mathbb R^3,p \cdot q := p^T q$ and $p \cdot q = 0$ implies orthogonality, the equations $q = Ap$ define tangent lines (in line coordinates) to the conic at points $p$.

He goes on to show the dual to the conic in line coordinates can be found from

$$
p^T A p = p^T A A^{-1} Ap = p^T A^T A^{-1} Ap = (Ap)^T A^{-1} (Ap) = q^T A^{-1} q
$$

where we have used the fact that $A = A^T$ since $A$ is symmetric.

From [the SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668231/preferred-means-for-finding-common-tangent-to-a-pair-of-ellipses-in-c) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic), for two real non-degenerate conics $f=0$ and $g=0$, the conics $g+tg=0$ form a pencil containing one or three degenerate conics. Hence, the conic

$$
q^T(A^{-1} + tB^{-1})q=0 \tag{1}
$$

has degenerates where

$$
det(A^{-1} + tB^{-1})=0 \tag{2}
$$

because that would make it factorable. Solving (2) yields a general cubic in $t$, for which Cardan gives a closed-form solution. Solving for $t$, plugging into

$$
(A^{-1} + tB^{-1})q=0 \tag{3}
$$

and finding the roots of each linear equation gives the pairs of points forming the tangents to the ellipses.